# What does MySQL "::1" hostname refer to?

Tags: mysql, ip, hostname

On a freshly installed (windows version of) MySQL 5.5.9

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user
```

gives:

```
user            host    

root        localhost   
root        127.0.0.1    
root        ::1  
localhost
```

But what IP/hostname does `::1` stand here for?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`::1` is the IPv6 address for localhost.

The details (incl.those relevant to the `Windows` case) are at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what MySQL uses; it has to do with what your system uses. The datatype of the host column is varchar; you could put just about anything in there...

Comment: More specifically, the IPv6 address for localhost is `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`, but all those zeros can be abbreviated, shortening the address down to `::1`.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll So, even if IPv6 is not installed in the system, the address will probably be still there? Seems interesting, esp. if one remembers MySQL's "pre-cooking" of some values in the `host` column (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-names.html).

Comment: oops! Found it myself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html.

Comment: @mlvljr Why are there 3 references to `localhost`, One by the name, by IPv4 address and one by `::1` (IPv6) ?

Comment: @SuvP I think the documentation and that book written by one of the maintainers (dont'  remember the title now, but the text is very clear) should address that; have not looked into this in a cpl of years, and don't have time to do that right now, sorry. [but could find that book a bit later today, if if you think you need a good read on MySQL]

Comment: @mlvljr Thanks for your time, Do drop in a link someday if you recall.

Comment: @SuvP The book is Paul DuBois' "MySQL" (Developer's library series), http://www.amazon.com/dp/0672329387 (the edition I was reading, there's also 5th one available now). Best wishes from Russia :)